# Create New TFS Work Item from selected code block

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

I want VS2013 (or by way of some VS add-in or extension) to let me select a code block and create a new TFS work item for it. This is a common scenario for me when I'm debugging code and find something that needs fixing later.

Ideally I want to be able to just highlight the buggy code, **R-click**, and `Create new work item...` and I'm not seeing a way to do this. Also, **R-click** a file from Solution Explorer and `Create new work item...`

1. Does such a mechanism exist?
2. Is there an extension or add-in that could give me this?

Comment: There is no built-in mechanism. If you're asking for recommendations on a tool, then your question is off-topic.

Comment: What exactly would you expect such a function to do?  Would it create a new bug, task, would it take the code that you'd highlighted and use that as the body for the work item?

Comment: Good qn. I haven't flushed out a full feature set or anything. I suppose at a minimum it would let me Create new WI, Select the WI type (Bug), and then throw up the "New Work Item" edit dialog. It would also provide some info like a pointer to the block's source file or even method or class name. Maybe auto-fill WI Title, e.g. "BUG: In [Method/Class]". Including the selected block would be nice. If it's a bug then include an exported Intellitrace or exception details (if any). Basically anything useful for later investigation but more importantly so I don't have to type out everything.

Comment: I ran into the need (want?) for this just today.  Seems like something an extension could do although I don't have any experience writing those.  I might file it away in my "projects to try out" list though...